# Apache error log levels. Should all the errors be eliminated?

Tags: php, apache

Question: Should I try to eliminate all the errors I get in apache error log produced by my PHP/Javascript application? The apache conf allows for the following log levels: Trace8-trace1, debug, info, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.

So far I set the loglevel to "debug" and I get errors like "Undefined index" or "Use of undefined constant prefix" but the application seems to be working just fine..

So is there any loglevel that I should set on apache and try to make sure I get absolutely no errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If PHP is generating those messages it's telling you that something's wrong. As a matter of course you should track down and rectify the causes of any notices, warnings or errors that PHP generates. Your application may be working now, but unresolved issues can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should try to resolve all the errors.

The advantages of correcting all the errors are:

- The log files will not be full of text
- Performance will be better because PHP doesn't have to identify and react to the errors
- Depending on the log configuration, you may save a lot of disk space
- Your code should be more robust

On the production server, set the log level fairly high.  On development servers set the log level low.